# elasticsearch - where fields is null

Tags: php, symfony, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, foselasticabundle

I'm trying to write query (with foselastica bundle) where value should be some id or can be null.

In mysql: `WHERE city.id = 1 OR city.id IS NULL`

I know that I should use exists and must not expression, but not working for me. Any advice?

```
    $query = new \Elastica\Query();

    if ($phrase) {
        $queryString = new \Elastica\Query\QueryString($phrase);
        $query->setQuery($queryString);
    }

    $filter = new \Elastica\Query\BoolQuery();

    $city = new \Elastica\Query\Match();
    $city->setFieldQuery('city.id', $cityId);
    $filter->addShould($city);

    $nullCity = new \Elastica\Query\Exists('city.id');
    $filter->addMustNot($nullCity);

    $query->setPostFilter($filter);
```

Comment: Read [Dealing with null and not null values in elasticsearch queries](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/ioyu/dealing-with-null-and-not-null-values-in-elasticsearch-queries). You need to use [missing](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_dealing_with_null_values.html).

Comment: missing query was removed from version 5. I'v got `no [query] registered for [missing]` exception. I can't find any useful example.

Answer (score 5):

You're close to it.
Try something like

```
$query = new \Elastica\BoolQuery();
// ...
$filter = new \Elastica\Query\BoolQuery();

$city = new \Elastica\Query\Match();
$city->setFieldQuery('city.id', $cityId);
$filter->addShould($city);

$nullCity = new BoolQuery();
$existQuery = new \Elastica\Query\Exists('city.id');
$nullCity->addMustNot($existQuery);
$filter->addShould($nullCity);

$query->addMust($filter);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I can't `addMust()` on `$query`: `Attempted to call an undefined method named \"addMust\" of class \"Elastica\\Query\".`

Comment: Except that I get `no [query] registered for [missing]`

Comment: My bad, $query needs to be a BoolQuery. `$query = new \Elastica\Query\BoolQuery();`

Comment: my `$filter` is `\Elastica\Query\BoolQuery()` object, should I add another one?

Comment: Yes, i think you can try. For the `Missing` query, it has been removed because it can be replaced by an exists query inside a must_not clause, like you said first. I was working on an older version of elastica. Check my updated answer